# Ubuntu 13.04/13.10 - low graphics mode/black screen after login

Tags: xorg

Since last week, my Ubuntu 13.04 installation started booting up in low graphics mode out of nowhere. I tried a number of solutions found on this site but to no avail. The other night, I decided to upgrade to 13.10 to see if the issue would be fixed in the process. Since then, the system starts fine, but when I login to my account, I'm just presented with a black screen. I switched to the terminal and did any necessary updates, but to no avail. I don't even know where to start debugging this issue, so I'd appreciate if someone could point me towards the first place to start looking?

Comment: Have you tried to re-configure `lightdm` display manager? You can reconfigure it by executing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and when ask to select default display manager, chose lightdm from the list. and then **OK**. After that try to re-start your system: `sudo reboot`

Comment: Just tried that, had no effect.